# UIWebView touches, gestures not working

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiwebview

UIWebView touches, gestures are not working if I Loaded the content of web view like this

```
NSString* htmlPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"source.bundle/index.html"];

NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:htmlPath];
NSLog(@"the urll==%@",url);

NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];

UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer =[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];

[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: Please show how you implement your function `panDetected:`

Comment: can u show your panDetected: method

Comment: Did you add the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` to your controller? Then set `recognizer.delegate` to the controller where your `panDetected:` Method is implemented

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try with this,

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]
    initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panSubview:)];
[subview addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

// play nice with subview's pan gesture
[YourView.panGestureRecognizer 
    requireGestureRecognizerToFail:panRecognizer];
```

Thanks